# Calculating Angle between two GPS Coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

i'm looking to create an angle attribute inside a layer of points that has a starting coordinate and a finishing coordinate. The angle needs to be 0-360.

Is there a field calculator command that I could use to calculate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the point is at the *finishing coordinate* and the *starting coordinate* is constant (in the example set to x0, y0), then use the following formula:

```
atan2($x - x0, $y - y0) / 0.017453
```

If the starting coordinate comes from an attribute simply replace x0 and y0 with the appropriate fields.

Comment: Only got round to doing this today months after asking the question. Worked perfectly! Thanks very much